# Need help with baked normal map

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I am really new to Blender and this is my first solo project. I created an axe in a low ploy and high poly version. On the high poly one I did some sculpting to bring in detail. After that I baked a normal map to put it on the low poly version. Now that the normal map was applied to the low poly mesh it looks strange in the render and don´t look like it supposed to. It looks like the high and low poly mesh is overlapping. But that can´t be the think because the all I don´t want in the render is hidden for rendering. Did i fucked up the normal map or what is the problem here...?

[image: this is what my problem looks like]

[image]

In the uploaded blend file parts of the axe are missing to stay under 30MB. You can see the problem anyway

Comment: Hi, @Metro. The link you provided for download was highly suspect, and so removed. Please choose another provider, or better yet,  isolate your problem to trim your file-size to under 30 Mb, and use https://blend-exchange.com/ .

Comment: Thank you, @Metro. :)

Comment: You didn't pack your normal map, but what does it give if you lower down the Stregth of the Normal Map down to 1 instead of 100?

Comment: @moonboots the stregth of 100 is just because I did some testig. Even if it is 1 the result is not better.

Comment: could you please pack your image and share your file again?

Comment: @moonboots Sorry it now shoudl be packed in I hope. Don´t wonder, half of the high poly axe is deletet because the file is bigger than 30mb, thats why the normal map looks a little different in the file than it looks on the picture in this post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work as it should. The *Strength* of your *Normal Map* is at 100, lower it down to 1. The details are very discrete but this is because they are very discrete on your high-poly. Here is what it gives if I create a low-angle light, as we can see the normal map effect is pretty faithful:

[image]

Comment: First of all ty for your time to help me!! Like I said the strength of the normal map was that high because I tested around and did not reset it. The Detail on top of the axe look fine, but the part of the axe that hit the wood in real life, has dents on the high poly mesh. In the low poly this dents are ther too, but you can see thr original shape of the low poly one. The front of the low poly shoudl look like the high poly one with dents

Comment: A normal map won't change the shape of the low-poly, it will only add fake 3D, the general shape of the low-poly will stay the same, if you want some dents you need to cut off the topology for real

Comment: Yeh i know.. In the anvil tutorial from blender guru he flattend some edges so it looks like the edges are broken and used. I just wanted to try this for my axe and make the front looked used. Seems like its not the way to do it right. Tanks for help :)